# Bluetooth error while making gmail login bot using selenium in python. But even the basic search for "Email" id element is also not found

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, gmail, selenium-chromedriver, bots

It does not seem to work and keeps giving me an error regarding Bluetooth drivers
Following is my code:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

usernameStr = 'putYourUsernameHere'
passwordStr = 'putYourPasswordHere'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?'
            'service=mail&continue=https://mail.google'
            '.com/mail/#identifier'))

# fill in username and hit the next button

username = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('next')
nextButton.click()

# wait for transition then continue to fill items

password = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Passwd")))

password.send_keys(passwordStr)

signInButton = browser.find_element_by_id('signIn')
signInButton.click()
```

This is the error of my code:-

**[11092:17164:0603/171812.746:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [17:18:12.747] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:723 GetBluetoothAdapterStaticsActivationFactory failed: Class not registered (0x80040154)**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "e:/python.py", line 62, in 
>       username = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
>     File "C:\Users\Bhaskar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
>       return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
>     File "C:\Users\Bhaskar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']
>     File "C:\Users\Bhaskar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Users\Bhaskar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="Email"]"}
>     (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)

Answer (score 0):

The username box doesn't have the id 'Email', but 'identifierId'. The same goes for the 'next' button.

Try something like this (might work a bit different for you, since I have Google in a different language).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

usernameStr = 'putYourUsernameHere'
passwordStr = 'putYourPasswordHere'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?'
            'service=mail&continue=https://mail.google'
            '.com/mail/#identifier'))

# fill in username and hit the next button

username = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

nextButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/span/span')
nextButton.click()
```

After this, Google blocks my attempts...

Comment: Google is blocking my attempt as well. The thing which I am trying to accomplish it to use this login form to automate Tinder login, and I'd like to use Google login for this case. In the Tinder bot login, id doesn't even detect the identifierId on login page.

Answer (score 0):

[image: id = identifierId]

ID you are looking for is "identifierId". try with that.